# Windows application to emboss date on photos

Tags: windows, gratis, photography, image-processing, exif

Looking for Windows application that will quickly and easily emboss a date onto JPG images (photographs), preferably obtained from the EXIF data.

Being able to perform the function on a group (batch) of images is a big plus, but not an absolute requirement.

A preview feature is also a plus, but not a requirement.

Must be cost-free (freeware).

Open-source is always a plus, but definitely *not* a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the batch conversion option in [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) to do this previously.

Here's a sample image with a date overlaid sampled from the photos EXIF data.

[image: Date overlay example image]

This can be accomplished through the IrfanView `Batch Conversion/Rename...` function and you can process multiple images as a batch.

### Instructions

1. Open Irfanview and choose the `Batch Conversion/Rename...` from the `File` menu
   [image: File menu screenshot]
2. In the `Batch conversion` window that opens there are numerous settings, but the one to add overlay text to the image is in the Advanced Options
   [image: Batch conversion screenshot]
3. In the `Set for all images` window you can enable the `Add overlay text` option, then control it via the `Settings` button.
   [image: Set for all images screenshot]
4. To use the date stamp from the image as the text enter something like this into the `Text:` box:

   > $T(%d/%m/%Y)

You'll need to play with the various settings in this area a fair amount to get the text positioned where you want and at the size that you want, but once set-up you can easily run it on multiple images.